# Всегда ли  не обособляются фразеологизмы?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Существует мнение, что фразеологические обороты никогда не обособляются, так как они имеют значение одного слова (обычно наречия). Эти обороты, действительно, чаще не обособляются, но это объясняется не свойством самого оборота, а СТРУКТУРОЙ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЙ, в которых они применяются, – ведь  и одиночное наречие тоже может ОБОСОБЛЯТЬСЯ или ОТДЕЛЯТЬСЯ ЗАПЯТОЙ в различных синтаксических конструкциях.
2. Попробуем показать на примерах,  что, как и всякое обстоятельство, фразеологизмы на основе деепричастных оборотов могут обособляться, если они занимают удобную для обособления позицию, или отделяться запятой, если они входят в однородный ряд членов.

2.1. Позиция, удобная для обособления

(1) И тут, очертя голову, я пустился во все тяжкие – оборот удален от сказуемого, он как бы "разрывает" фразу.

(2) Но: Не бросайся очертя голову, но и не слишком раздумывай  – тесное единство с глаголом,ударение падает на оборот.

(3) Мальчики бросились в проход и спрятались там, затаив дыхание – ударение на втором сказуемом (и на обособленном обороте).

(4) Но: Мы покорно сидели затаив дыхание, не решаясь шевельнуться  – тесное единство с глаголом,ударение падает на оборот.

2.2.   Фразеологизм в роли второго обстоятельства отделяется запятой:

(5) Отвечаю честно, положа руку на сердце – однородные члены.

Comment: Дорогие мои друзья, я вас всех очень люблю, но все-таки не могу с вами согласиться. И я очень надеюсь, что противоположные чувства не мешают вам в поисках истины быть объективными. Также  в качестве своих «адвокатов»  я могу  привлечь только наших русских классиков или  просто обычных писателей. Вот несколько примеров: 
1)  Какъ только увидѣлъ я, что надо мнѣ умирать, — тотчасъ страсть какъ хотѣлось мнѣ жить. И тутъ я, очертя голову, пустился во всѣ тяжкія. (Г. Успенский).

Comment: 2) Неужели ты думаешь, что я какъ дуракъ пошелъ, очертя голову? (Ф.Достоевский»
3) Робинзон Крузо. Затем отец настойчиво и очень благожелательно стал упрашивать меня не ребячиться, не бросаться, очертя голову, в омут нужды и страданий… 
4) Современные тексты. Скорч, сломя голову, бросается на помощь, и, разумеется, влипает в неприятности.

Comment: Нет такого правила, для которого не нашлось бы примера использования вопреки. Но это не отменяет правила. Так, случаи левитации не отменяют закона земного притяжения.

Comment: Давайте уже здесь и сейчас считать, что есть орфография базовая - для школьников и абитуриентов. Это орфография правил и ссылок, без них сейчас не обойтись. Но есть орфография художественных текстов, которой в обозначенных рамках тесновато.Я знаю правила и стараюсь им соответствовать при ответах - у меня нет желания "путать" людей, я могу разговаривать на языке правил. Но сама я работаю без правил - пользуюсь грамматикой и словарями. Только чтобы отказаться от правил, мне пришлось творчески поработать с очень большим количеством правил, сравнить их и проанализировать.

Comment: И уж конечно я эти правила не изобретаю. Почему бы нам на нашем форуме не пойти немного дальше узких рамок школьной программы. Представьте себе, что бы было, если вас заставляли ходить строго по правилам. Вы бы когда-нибудь научились ходить? И представьте себе, что будет с языком творческих людей, если мы будем постоянно втискивать его в эти правила. Один из наших писателей очень точно выразился на эту тему, сказав:"Надо мной всегда висит Дамоклов меч синтаксиса".

Comment: Дорогая София, последний Ваш пост мне очень нравится, но он противоречив. Вы предлагаете "не втискивать"язык творческих людей в правила, а сами же призываете создать новые правила, только двух уровней. Хватит тех правил, которые есть, надо научиться ими пользоваться, как это делают настоящие писатели.И тутъ я, очертя голову, пустился во всѣ тяжкія. (Г. Успенский).- это худ. приём, разрушение фразеологизма, когда рядом с переносным стоит прямое значение.Очертя голову - проведя круг вокруг головы - сделав защиту. Тогда люди знали смысл очерчивания головы, мы забыли.

Comment: 1
Скорч, сломя голову, бросается на помощь, и, разумеется, влипает в неприятности.-авторская пунктуация-значение пояснения. Но это пояснение возвращает нас опять-таки к прямому смыслу с глагольным значением.  Мы читаем, не вдумываясь в смысл, а надо бы. Но ученикам, конечно, нужно следовать правилам, так как они неумело используют авторскую пунктуацию и создают корявые фразы.

Answer (score 3):

София, не придумывайте новых правил.

```
Как и всякое обстоятельство, фразеологизмы на основе деепричастных оборотов могут обособляться, если они занимают удобную для обособления позицию
```

Где Вы такое нашли?.Фразеологический оборот на основе деепричастия НЕ ОБОСОБЛЯЕТСЯ НИКОГДА, если обособляется, это уже не фразеологизм. Исключением являются ТОЛЬКО "по совести говоря" и "судя по всему", выступающие в роли вводных слов.

http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_2_5_2
http://www.xliby.ru/jazykoznanie/spravochnik_po_pravopisaniyu_proiznosheniyu_literaturnomu_redaktirovaniyu/p3.php#metkadoc26
http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=784d4197-238a-4897-b294-88b442e5a5c1

```
И тут, очертя голову, я пустился во все тяжкие – оборот удален от сказуемого, он как бы "разрывает" фразу.
```

здесь тоже не должно быть запятых(или как авторское обособление с желанием пояснить, объяснить) .Сама фраза с этим разрывом звучит коряво,я бы исправила как ошибку.

```
  "Мальчики бросились в проход и спрятались там, затаив дыхание – ударение на втором сказуемом (и на обособленном обороте)".
```

Это не фразеологизм, когда мы спрячемся в страхе, мы в самом деле почти не дышим, чтобы не выдать себя дыханием.

```
(5) Отвечаю честно, положа руку на сердце – однородные члены.
```

-Про однородные члены никто не говорит, это не обособление.

Похоже, у Вас проблемы с  фразеологией.

Comment: Полностью согласна. Мне тоже при чтении фразу с "очертя голову"хотелось поправить.

Comment: >(1) И тут, очертя голову, я пустился

Ну конечно, это искусственное образование, которое упорно навязывает читателю чертёжные манипуляции. И даже то, что этот пример из словаря взят, не служит убедительным аргументом в правомерности такого отрыва оборота от сказуемого.

Answer (score 1):

(1) И тут, очертя голову, я пустился во все тяжкие – оборот удален от сказуемого, он как бы "разрывает" фразу

(2) Но: Не бросайся очертя голову, но и не слишком раздумывай – тесное единство с глаголом,ударение падает на оборот.
*И в первом, и во втором примерах фразеологизм не обособляется, я согласна с Людмилой - не надо придумывать новых правил и запутывать саму себя.*

(3) Мальчики бросились в проход и спрятались там, затаив дыхание – ударение на втором сказуемом (и на обособленном обороте). 
В этом примере нет фразеологизма: "затаив"- деепричастие = очень тихо, тайно, чтобы никто не слышал, как мы дышим; "дыхание" - обычное существительное, а всё вместе - обособленное обстоятельство, выраженное деепричастным оборотом.

(4) Но: Мы покорно сидели затаив дыхание, не решаясь шевельнуться – тесное единство с глаголом,ударение падает на оборот.

2.2. Фразеологизм в роли второго обстоятельства отделяется запятой:

(5) Отвечаю честно, положа руку на сердце – однородные члены. 
Да, в данном случае перед фразеологизмом ставим запятую, но лишь потому, как верно сказала Людмила, что слово "честно" и фразеологизм "положа руку на сердце" - это однородные члены предложения и, считаю, что семантические синонимы.